# Fonts specific to a country?

Tags: fonts

I am working on a multilingual book about some European Union countries. The selected are: Poland, Greece, Spain, Italy, Romania, Czech Republic, Austria,  Turkey, Estonia. I wish to write chapter about a country using a font in some way specific  for it. The Polish (free) fonts are, e.g., Antykwa Toruńska or Antykwa Półtawskiego.

I would be grateful for any suggestion concerning the remaining countries.

Comment: Just to clarify: You would rather use a distinctive font for each chapter than a font that provides characters, accents, and other typographic marks used in the various languages of the countries you list, right?

Comment: Yes, Mico: a distinctive font for each chapter.

Comment: should the fonts be free, or can they be also commercial?

Comment: @michal.h21: I prefer free fonts, but any piece of information will be valuable.

Comment: And the TeX question is....?

Comment: @topskip: From a FAQ: "If you have a question about ...

    
    Related software and tools (...)

... then you're in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: This question has been closed as off-topic as we don't see anything related to TeX. It should be asked on a site more specific to "design" or "typography". If you think this closing is unjustified, you should edit your question, make it clear in what way it is TeX related and flag it for moderator attention ('plz open it again' or so). IMO doing the typesetting with TeX doesn't justify a design question by its own _on this site_. (I like you question though.)

Comment: (FAQ) I like the question, but it does not contain anything related to TeX. I see "font usage in specific countries" which is clearly _not_ related to TeX - even if many TeX users are well aware of the fonts they use.

Comment: Przemysław, [Graphic Design.SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) should be the on topic site for you. Add the `fonts` and `typography` tags.

Comment: @Speravir: Thank you very much! I had no idea that this site exists. The question is closed, so I cannot add  points of reputation, upvoting your answer (only a comment). Or maybe there is such a possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking of the Czech republic, there were some famous typemakers in the 20th century, like Oldřich Menhart and Vojtěch Preissig. They created some original typefaces, some information can be found in [this article](http://www.typotheque.com/articles/czechoslovak_typography), or in [another article](http://rosettatype.com/index.php?action=portal/viewContent&cntId_content=2901).

Unfortunately, I don't know about any free digitalised version of their typefaces, there is only lot of commercial versions, like [Maiola](http://davi.cz/Writings/2011_Maiola-experience-the-czechness.html), [Menhart](http://www.linotype.com/155238/Menhart-family.html).František Storm created some fonts inspired with [Josef Týfa](http://www.stormtype.com/people-josef-tyfa.html) and [Vojtěch Preissig](http://www.stormtype.com/people-vojtech-preissig.html). Other fonts inspired with Czech tradition are [Skolar](http://www.rosettatype.com/Skolar) and [Nara](http://www.typotheque.com/articles/nara_-_the_typeface_that_never_existed) which is really interesting, because it was originally designed in 1988 using METAFONT.

Only good free Czech font I know is František Storm's [Lido](http://www.stormtype.com/family-lido-stf.html), but it is based on Times. Good thing about Lido is that there is also [support](http://www.cstug.cz/stormtype/slido.html) for traditional TeX, not only XeTeX or LuaTeX .

Answer (score 1):

From the spanish point of view I can recommend the Universidad de Salamanca's font.  I'm not sure about its name, but you can find information here:

http://www.dafont.com/universitas-studii-salamantini.font

Comment: It is a good suggestion, but I need a font with both uppercase and lowercase glyphs.

Comment: Now that you mentioned it, I've never seen in Salamanca any sign written with lower case...

Comment: @PrzemysławScherwentke maybe the font of "El Quijote" could be useful?

Comment: It might be one of used spanish fonts, but not the only one, because it mimics handwriting.